# How to check up home screen grid 4x4 or 4x5 or else?

Tags: android, widget, grid, homescreen

I have home screen widget and I want add sizes *x5 to it. But I do not want that users with home screen grid smaller than 5x5  can see this types of my widget in widgets list.

How I can check up grid size of home screen?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can check up grid size of home screen?

You can't. The home screen does not even have to have a grid system.